# Google Chrome Extension: Source on Load

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I need to gather the source code of a webpage on load and send it to a text file.

Preferred specs:

- On webpage load
- Save the entire HTML source
- Overwrites any previous text in the file being saved to(do not append).

If this is not possible, i then would need the URL of the page on load instead of the Source.

Is any of this possible through a Chrome extension (if possible as well to be portable to other browsers such as IE and Firefox).

Comment: Forget about portability, that's not happening any time soon. It is possible as a Chrome extension. Which part of the process is the problem for you?

Comment: i've never written an extension before and have never touched javascript in my life.

Comment: Then I suppose it's going to take some studying. Good resources: [JavaScript: The Good Parts](http://www.amazon.com/JavaScript-Good-Parts-Douglas-Crockford/dp/0596517742), [Mozilla Developer Network on JavaScript](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript), [Chrome Extensions site](http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/), and the new HTML5 [`FileWriter`](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/file/filesystem/) API.